# How To Modify Data In a c++ Linked List 3

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

i have create coding for insert and search for book for library system but now i'm stuck on how to update the book detail that i have insert?

```
    void Node::insert(char *barcode,char *title,char *author,char *quantity,char *price)
{
    daftar *newnode=NULL;
    newnode=new daftar(barcode,title,author,quantity,price);
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        newnode->setnext(head);
        head=newnode;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you at least add how the update function looks like?

Comment: Firstly,enter the bar code the search the book we want to edit then,we edit all the information of the book

Answer (score 0):

Try something like, basic way how link lists are used.

```
void Node::update(char *barcode,char *title,char *author,char *quantity,char *price)
{
    Node* tmp = new Node();
    tmp = head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
       if(strcmp(tmp->title,title) == 0)
       {
        tmp->barcode = barcode;
        tmp->author = author;
        tmp->quantity = quantity;
        tmp->price = price;
        return;
       } 
      else
        tmp = tmp->next;
     }
}
```